# RxJava withLatestFrom not working

Tags: java, rx-java

I expected result as followings after running my sample code.
   atest
   btest
   ctest
but actually nothing happened.
please let me know what is wrong with my code.

```
    Subject<String, String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.onNext("test");

    Observable<String> observable = Observable.from(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}).repeat(2);
    observable.withLatestFrom(subject, (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2)
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `withLatestFrom` drops values until the other observable produces its first value. This happens often if the main source is synchronous and rushes through before the other can emit.

Second, `PublishSubject` emits to those who are subscribed but in your example, at the line `subject.onNext()` there is no one there to observe the value and as such is dropped.

You can use `BehaviorSubject` instead which remembers the very last value and `withLatestFrom` will also see it immediately.